# Find patterns in strings and concatenate unique parts in R

Tags: regex, r, string

Conciser having 2 strings `s1` and `s2`. How is it possible to concatenate only those parts in these strings, which are unique, and leave non unique parts as is. Let `/` be the separator between concatenated parts. The desired result looks like this:

```
s1 <- "very big house"
s2 <- "very small house"

some_function(s1,s2)
"very big/small house" #// desired result.
```

Usually leading and tailing charters are the same for both strings and the differences appear only in the middle.
More examples of desired result:

```
# a
s1 <- "1b"; s2 <- "2b"
"1/2b" # <- new string

# b
s1 <- "a_1_b"; s2 <- "a_2_b"
"a_1/2_b" # <- new string

# c
s1 <- "a"; s2 <- "b"
"a/b" # <- new string
```

Comment: Try with `paste(s1, s2, sep="/")`  If there are duplicates, use `strsplit` to split into parts, concatenate both, get the `unique` and then `paste`  It is not clear from the various examples that if you consider `word` as unique or `character` as unique

Comment: Are there any other rules for the strings? like do they all have the same format in terms of number and letters? that is if string a looks like `"<letter>_<number>_<letter>"` will the other string follow the same format?

Comment: @akrun unique is sequence of charters.

Comment: @konkked the structure of strings is not known in advance: this is the main difficulty I'm facing.  
Is there any way to determine how many leading and how many tailing characters match in 2 strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix <- function(vs1,vs2,sep=' ') {
    ## cycle string vectors to same length
    vsl <- max(length(vs1),length(vs2));
    vs1 <- rep(vs1,len=vsl);
    vs2 <- rep(vs2,len=vsl);
    ## precompute character splits
    ss1 <- strsplit(vs1,'');
    ss2 <- strsplit(vs2,'');
    ## iterate over each pair of strings
    sapply(seq_along(vs1),function(si) {
        s1 <- vs1[si];
        s2 <- vs2[si];
        s1l <- length(ss1[[si]]);
        s2l <- length(ss2[[si]]);
        slmin <- min(s1l,s2l);
        ## handle trivial case of exact equality
        if (s1==s2) return(s1);
        ## get prefix and suffix lengths
        if (slmin==0L) { ## empty string cannot result in a prefix or suffix
            pl <- sl <- 0L;
        } else {
            eq <- ss1[[si]][seq_len(slmin)]==ss2[[si]][seq_len(slmin)];
            pl <- if (all(eq)) slmin else if (eq[1L]==T) which(!eq)[1L]-1L else 0L;
            eq <- rev(ss1[[si]])[seq_len(slmin)]==rev(ss2[[si]])[seq_len(slmin)];
            sl <- if (all(eq)) slmin else if (eq[1L]==T) which(!eq)[1L]-1L else 0L;
        }; ## end if
        ## paste together prefix, sep-pasted middles, and suffix
        m1 <- substr(s1,pl+1L,s1l-sl);
        m2 <- substr(s2,pl+1L,s2l-sl);
        paste0(substr(s1,1L,pl),paste(sep=sep,m1,m2),substr(s1,s1l-sl+1L,s1l));
    });
}; ## end pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix()
```

Demo:

```
pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix('a','b');
## [1] "a b"
pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix('a','b','/');
## [1] "a/b"
s1 <- 'very big house'; s2 <- 'very small house'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "very big/small house"
s1 <- '1b'; s2 <- '2b'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "1/2b"
s1 <- 'a_1_b'; s2 <- 'a_2_b'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "a_1/2_b"
s1 <- 'ab'; s2 <- 'ab'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "ab"
s1 <- 'xab'; s2 <- 'ab'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "x/ab"
s1 <- 'ab'; s2 <- 'abx'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "ab/x"
s1 <- 'abx'; s2 <- 'ab'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "abx/"
s1 <- 'ab'; s2 <- 'xab'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "/xab"
s1 <- ''; s2 <- 'x'; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "/x"
s1 <- 'x'; s2 <- ''; pasteMergePrefixAndSuffix(s1,s2,'/');
## [1] "x/"
```